# Zephyr application build fail

Tags: nrf52, zephyr-rtos

I am trying to build my Zephyr application for NRF52 but have an error
It seems that the compiler has a problem with the include:  **#include "cbor.h"**
I updated my **CMakeLists.txt** with the relevant library location
I appreciate any ideas regarding this issue - thanks

Attached CMakeLists.txt and the output of the west build for your review

Build command:

```
west build -b nrf52_pca10040
```

[CMakeLists.txt](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g5AOaTqb5CuFOJhAU0kqeugHXHUlqPrZ7ogn0-poiO4/edit)

[Output](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z9t2ttoE-PysztapoRbmUlJE9-Y-CuuQpy8zKaEnkHM/edit)

Comment: Did you initialize the zephyr environment ? And cloned everything using west? West is meant to clone all dependent components which is needed for Zephyr to work

Comment: Thanks this matter was solved, I was using old Zephyr project with new Zephyr SDK